# Why does \n not create a new line in a list?

Tags: python, list, newline, python-3.7

I am trying to make a multi-line input program but when I append \n to my list it does not print or create a new line. As far as I know, it just disappears

```
first = input("input message here")
line_num = 2
line_content = []
for each_line in range(lines-1):
    nextLINE= input("             line"+ str(line_num))
    line_content.append(nextLINE)
    final = (str(line_content)).upper()
    list(final).append('\n ')
    line_num += 1
print(first.upper())
print(final)
```

If I input 3 lines:

line 1: hello world,
line 2: this does not work,
line 3: pls help me fix this

it returns:

HELLO WORLD

['THIS DOES NOT WORK', 'PLS HELP ME FIX THIS']

What I want it to return is:

HELLO WORLD

THIS DOES NOT WORK

PLS HELP ME FIX THIS

Comment: The question is unclear. Please make a [mcve].

Comment: Replace `line_content.append(nextLINE)` with `line_content.append(nextLINE.upper())` and `print(final)` with `for line in line_content: print(line)`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Are you aware about `string.join` in python? E.g. `"\n".join(line_content)`

Comment: wjandrea sorry, im new to stack overflow, still figuring things out. I will work on that next time

Comment: stovfl thanks a lot! this worked perfectly

Comment: Alex Yu no I was not aware of using join in this way. thanks for showing me!

Comment: `list(final).append('\n ')` doesn't at all do what you think it does. It creates a new list object in memory, appends the `\n` to the list, and then that list you created just goes away immediately because there isn't any variable that references it.

Comment: I think what you want is something more like `final = final + '\n'`